# Neo4j - can't retrieve data containing escaped characters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Queries are not returning the data when string contains escaped character.
What I am doing wrong here?

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (c: Country{country_name:'Côte d\'Ivoire'}) return c;
==> +---+
==> | c |
==> +---+
==> +---+
==> 0 row
==> 7 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (c: Country) where (c.country_name = 'Côte d\'Ivoire') return c;
==> +---+
==> | c |
==> +---+
==> +---+
==> 0 row
==> 16 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (c: Country) where (c.country_name =~ '.*Ivoire') return c;
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> | c                                        |
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[3349]{country_name:"Cote d'Ivoire"} |
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> 1 row
==> 13 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

Comment: This may depend on how your data got into the DB.  Is it possible what you put in had a different encoding than what you're querying?

Comment: I am using UTF8 all the way.

Comment: Did you try: `where (c.country_name = "Côte d'Ivoire")` ?

Comment: Oh, please also note, that in your result it doesn't show `ô` but just `o` !!

Comment: The ô appears on my screen, it is just missing here on the internet.

Comment: $ match (c:Country) where (c.country_name = "Côte d'Ivoire") return c.country_name;
+----------------+
| c.country_name |
+----------------+
+----------------+
0 row
22 ms

Comment: $ match (c:Country) where (c.country_name =~ '.*Ivoire') return c.country_name;
+-----------------+
| c.country_name  |
+-----------------+
| "Cote d'Ivoire" |
+-----------------+
1 row
12 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that in one node the value was Cote d'Ivoire and in another node was Côte d'Ivoire.
I made both values the same and now is working.